# Create a view to show a user his or her recent activity

Tags: 7, users, views

I am creating a view that would display the activity of the users. When user 1 is logged in, it would show the activities of user1 only...his node uploads, his comments etc,,,such as:

User1  commented on "Some Artcile"   Time
User1 Uploaded his article "Some BLOG"  Time

How should i proceed. I am using Views3, and Drupal7

Comment: "Activity" is quite a broad subject, to broad, in my opinion for this question to make sense.

Comment: How are you tracking this activity?  The Activity Module?  The Heartbeat module?  Both of these provide blocks for displaying the activity by default...

Comment: i am using activity but i read that message would be a better choice for that purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show latest nodes and comments in one view you would new a "[views union](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31786/how-to-create-a-union-of-two-views)" which is still a tricky thing to do in views.

You could write a custom module to run the query and display the results. The query would look something like this:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT n.nid, n.title, type, 'comment' as action, max(c.created) as postdate, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(u.name)) as users
      FROM comment c INNER join node n ON c.nid = n.nid
      INNER JOIN users u on c.uid = u.uid
      WHERE c.uid IN (:uids)
      AND c.created > :timestamp
      AND c.status = 1
      GROUP BY n.nid, n.title, n.type
    UNION
      SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.type, 'node' as action, max(n.created) as postdate, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(u.name)) as users
      FROM node n INNER JOIN users u on n.uid = u.uid
      WHERE n.uid IN (:uids)
      AND n.created > :timestamp
      AND n.status = 1
      GROUP BY n.nid, n.title, n.type
      ORDER BY postdate desc";
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the  [heartbeat](http://drupal.org/project/heartbeat) or the [message module](http://drupal.org/project/message) and let them do the heavy lifting for you

Answer (score 1):

In the views UI under "filter criteria" you can add a "Content: Author uid" filter and that will filter by user. You will also need to set up a "relationship" under with "Content user". However as mentioned this question is very broad, but maybe this will help you get started