# Forum posts and replies

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have a requirement where I need to show latest discussions (using [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module) using views. The tricky thing here is that both replies and topics need to be treated equally and the one more recent should be displayed on top even if they are part of same thread.

For example, user A creates a new topic/post X, B replied on it (lets call that reply Y) and then user C created another topic Z. In such case the order of the items in the module should be as following.

- Topic Z
- Reply Y
- Topic X

Note that even the reply is shown. Now, topics and replies can be sorted independently in a view however how to sort them in combination is the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you need is a "[union of 2 views][1]", see details there


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31786/how-to-create-a-union-of-two-views